# How can 「うん」 be used to mean both "yes" and "no?"

Tags: meaning

I was told by my Japanese teacher that 「うん」 can be used as a casual way to say "yes" *as well as* "no." If this is true, how can you tell the difference, absent any additional information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible that your teacher was talking about how to respond to negative questions in Japanese. [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/the-reality-of-answering-%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%88-to-a-negative-question) is a good explanation for that.

In this case, though, I think your teacher was talking about うん vs ううん.

A straightforward うん with a falling intonation means yes. A lengthened ううん, often with high, then lower, then middle pitch can be used to express doubt, denial or disagreement (it may be helpful to ask your teacher to demonstrate).

As oldergod says, this is often used when answering a negative-question, but it doesn't have to be used this way. In my friend's copy of Genki I have seen something like:

> A: 子供の時、元気だった？
>   B: うん、元気だった　／　ううん、元気じゃなかった

Comment: On a side note, I really need to go through Genki myself. I've been stuck with some pretty awful textbooks in my Japanese classes so far!

Comment: I know this is old, but I've just seen "う…ん" in a book I'm reading in response to a positive question - is that yes or no? 
Judging by the context it means no, but it looks halfway between うん and ううん :)

Comment: @user3379824 not something I’ve seen before and difficult to say without context but I guess it’s conveying uncertainty?

Answer (score 3):

By default, it means yes/correct.

But regardless of the question form: negative or positive, the うん confirms it. ううん denies it.

In English, *I am not sure* but I don't think you would say "No, I am going" after being asked "Aren't you going to school today ?". But in Japanese, ううん would be used.