# What is the role of そうよ in そうよ存外怖くはないわ?

Tags: translation, meaning, song-lyrics

I heard そうよ存外怖くはないわ in a song, but I don't get the meaning of そうよ.

Answer (score 3):

そうよ just means "That's right" or "Yes" (or [sometimes "No"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2908/5010) in a negative sentence). そう means "so" or "that way", and よ is a sentence-end particle (sounds feminine [because it directly follows a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12987/5010)).

If this is taken from [this song](https://www5.atwiki.jp/hmiku/pages/33080.html), this そうよ is simply used to emphasize 怖くはない — "**No**, I'm not afraid". (Please always try to include the link to the original song; it's often difficult to interpret a line from a song unless we have the whole context.)